# swift4: TableView setSelected function called twice on iPad click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, swift4

I am new in swift4 and this is my first table view implementation.

I am using iPad for developing application and I can not resolve issue that table view setSelected function is called twice on click and always selected value is equals to true

As I saw in Web such behavior is only on [iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31836542/556526)

So what is workaround fir this issue

My code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkImage: UIImageView!    
var showing = false

 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            if showing == false {
                checkImage.isHidden = false
                showing = true
            }
            else {
                checkImage.isHidden = true
                showing = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where does that code live?  In your custom `UITableViewCell` class?  if you set an Xcode breakpoint in `setSelected`, what functions call `setSelected`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `deselectRow(at:animated:)` in `didSelectRow`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at:indexPath animated:true)
}
```

Comment: This is instead of setSelected function or in addition?

Comment: With this you should get setSelected called once, so you can use it in addition.